# How to invoke execution of a container in AWS Sagemaker when REST API is called?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-sagemaker

I have packaged an application in as a docker image. Uploaded it to ECR and pulled this docker image into the AWS Sagemaker instance. I am able to to execute this docker image manually via terminal inside Sagemaker.

But I want to trigger this docker image only when invoked by a REST API by the end user from outside (internet). I saw Endpoints can be created in Sagemaker however in all the docs that I've read, it expects models to be created and configured. For example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/create-multi-model-endpoint.html. But in my case the model is inside the docker image itself hence there is no model to configure.

Therefore, how can I execute this docker image in AWS Sagemaker when invoked by REST API?

Answer (score 1):

If you have baked the model into the image that is okay. You can then just leave model data s3 location empty. For SageMaker endpoints the container needs to respond to /ping and /invocations.

1. /ping - return 200s
2. /invocations - make prediction against models and return the result.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html